# Liip ImagineBundle custom resize without caching

Tags: symfony, caching, upload, liipimaginebundle

I am using Liip ImagineBundle for managing the pictures in an auction listings project. The setup is as follows - when an auction listing is being created I am using Plupload to upload the picture set (with AJAX prior to persisting the auction). The pictures are uploaded into `/pictures/temp` folder with a temporary hash name. Upon persisting the entity, a Doctrine Subscriber renames the uploads in the temporary folder to use a format:

`{AUCTION-ID}-{SIZE}-{TIMESTAMP}.{EXTENSION}`

where the size is the version of the image - XL, large, medium, etc. and based on the timestamp creates a subfolder as:

`/pictures/{YEAR}/{MONTH}/{DAY}/{PICTURE}`

This allows for preventing millions of pictures to end up in a single folder and slow the file system. I am using a custom file loader and cache manager to resolve the pictures based on the timestamp. It all works perfectly fine but I have a request to display the uploaded pictures in a preview while doing the Plupload. The problem is in the resizing and caching with the ImagineBundle. What I would like to achieve is have the uploaded picture (the `{HASH}.jpg` in `/pictures/temp`) be resized to a specific size and at the same time a thumbnail to be generated off that as `{HASH}-thumb.jpg`. I know I can make it with another file loader and a cache manager but I was wondering whether it is possible to done via the bundle in some other way which is simpler as both these files are temporary ones and will be deleted upon the creation of the auction.

Comment: Anyone from the community to share his findings on this matter? thanks